# C++ string implementation error

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a basic `string` class in C++. However, I am stuck on the `append()` function. It would like it to be `Hello World`, but it results as `Hello ÍWorlýýýý««««««««þ`:

```
#define __START namespace lib{
#define __END }

__START
class string
{
public:
    string(const char* s)
    {
        _str = s;
    }
    const char operator[](int position)
    {
        return _str[position];
    }
    void operator=(string s)
    {
        _str = s.c_str();
    }
    void append(string s)
    {
        size_t nlength = (length() + s.length());
        char* nstr = new char[nlength];
        for (int i = 0; i < length(); ++i)
        {
            nstr[i] = _str[i];
        }
        for (int i = length() + 1; i < nlength; ++i)
        {
            nstr[i] = s[(i - length() - 1)];
        }
        _str = const_cast<const char*>(nstr);
    }
    void operator+=(string s)
    {
        append(s);
    }
    const char* c_str()
    {
        return _str;
    }
    size_t length()
    {
        return strlen(_str);
    }
    std::string str()
    {
        return _str;
    }
private:
    const char* _str;
};
__END
```

---

```
int main()
{
    lib::string s = "Hello ";
    s.append("World"); // s += "World";
    std::cout << s.c_str();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: By all means, use a different name for your string class. `string` conflicts with `std::string`. Of course you could have `yournamespace::string`, but it's better to avoid the confusion altogether.

Comment: @DanielDaranas And I would bet $1000 that OP is `using namespace std;` anyway.

Comment: You need to allocate nlength + 1 then add '\0' to end of string

Comment: You're not leaving room for the trailing null character in your strings.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the fact that c-strings are null-terminated. "Hello" may have a length of 5 but requires 6 characters of memory to hold the terminating '\0'.

Comment: Also, wtf is `_str = const_cast<const char*>(nstr);`? You don't seem to get the idea of `const`-qualification. And that function leaks memory as well. (you don't `delete[]` the previous string.)

Comment: @H2C03 - I dont do `using namespace std;` anyway :) (for safety reasons)

Comment: Also, what's with the `const char*` member and the `const_cast<const char*>` cast? Is that a pattern I'm not aware of?

Comment: Double underscores are reserved tokens in all contexts, leading underscores are reserved tokens in global scope, and leading underscores followed by capital letters are also reserved in all scopes.  I would get rid of your `#define` preprocessor magic and just put the namespace scope inline.

Comment: Also, your constructor and operator= should make local copies.

Comment: @Joe "I dont do `using namespace std;` anyway :) (for safety reasons) " - yay, ***you, sir, are awesome.***

Comment: Now that we're talking a bit about everything, you're not planning to actually _use_ this class, are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **tons of problems** with your code, so let's do this step by step.

First, you don't need your preprocessor magic for the namespace, but just a basic `namespace mynamespace{}`.

Secondly, it is ideal to create a `basic_string` class, so that it can be used with different character types. `char` / `wchar_t`, e.t.c.

**Problems with your class:**

1) `private: const char *_str;`. The pointer will be modified, so the `const` is useless.

2) There are no `typedef`s. You need them if you are attempting to re-implement a STL class. (Explained in example)

3) Use an `allocator`. This way you can `construct`, and `destroy` elements, `allocate`, and `deallocate` memory. You will be certain to keep your memory a lot safer this way.

4) Strings must be null terminated. That means an extra `'\0'` at the end, meaning you will have to allocate an extra byte for that. Strings are null terminated, because it is a way of telling the code to stop reading the string.

5) You are assigning to a string which has not been allocated. `_str = s.c_str();` could easily crash, depending on your compiler, because you are writing to non-allocated memory.

6) Use const references, rather than normal types for your parameters (`string` = `const string &`). You also need this for your copy constructor `basic_string(const _Myt &)`.

I still may not have highlighted *all* of the problems

**Example `basic_string` class**

```
template < typename _Elem, typename _Traits = std::char_traits<_Elem>, typename _Alloc = std::allocator<_Elem> > class basic_string
{
public:
    typedef basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc> _Myt;
    typedef _Elem value_type;
    typedef _Traits traits_type;
    typedef _Alloc  allocator_type;
    typedef value_type *pointer;
    typedef const value_type *const_pointer;
    typedef value_type *iterator;
    typedef const value_type *const_iterator;
    typedef value_type &reference;
    typedef const value_type &const_reference;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

    basic_string()
    {
        __data = _Alloc().allocate(1);
        _Alloc().construct(&__data[0], '\0');
    }

    basic_string(const_pointer _Init)
    {
        int count = 0;
        __data = _Alloc().allocate(_Traits::length(_Init) + 1);
        for (const_iterator i = &_Init[0]; i != &_Init[_Traits::length(_Init)]; ++i, ++count)
        {
            _Alloc().construct(&__data[count], *i);
        }
        _Alloc().construct(&__data[_Traits::length(_Init)], '\0');
    }

    basic_string(const _Myt &_Init)
    {
        if (this != &_Init)
        {
            int count = 0;
            __data = _Alloc().allocate(_Traits::length(_Init.__data) + 1);
            for (const_iterator i = &_Init.__data[0]; i != &_Init.__data[_Traits::length(_Init.__data)]; ++i, ++count)
            {
                _Alloc().construct(&__data[count], *i);
            }
            _Alloc().construct(&__data[_Traits::length(_Init.__data)], '\0');
        }
        else
        {
            __data = _Alloc().allocate(1);
            _Alloc().construct(&__data[0], '\0');
        }
    }

    ~basic_string()
    {
        if (__data)
        {
            size_type tmp = size();
            for (iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i)
            {
                _Alloc().destroy(i);
            }
            _Alloc().deallocate(__data, tmp);
        }
    }

    _Myt &assign(const_pointer _Rhs)
    {
        int count = 0;
        reserve(_Traits::length(_Rhs) + 1);
        for (const_iterator i = &_Rhs[0]; i != &_Rhs[_Traits::length(_Rhs)]; ++i, ++count)
        {
            _Alloc().construct(&__data[count], *i);
        }
        _Alloc().construct(&__data[_Traits::length(_Rhs)], '\0');
        return *this;
    }

    _Myt &operator=(const_pointer _Rhs)
    {
        return assign(_Rhs);
    }

    _Myt &append(const_pointer _Rhs)
    {
        int count = size();
        reserve(size() + _Traits::length(_Rhs) + 1);
        for (const_iterator i = &_Rhs[0]; i != &_Rhs[_Traits::length(_Rhs)]; ++i, ++count)
        {
            _Alloc().construct(&__data[count], *i);
        }
        _Alloc().construct(&__data[count], '\0');
        return *this;
    }

    _Myt &operator+=(const_pointer _Rhs)
    {
        return append(_Rhs);
    }

            iterator begin()
    {
        return &__data[0];
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return &__data[size()];
    }

    size_type size()
    {
        return _Traits::length(__data);
    }

    _Myt &swap(basic_string<_Elem> &_Rhs)
    {
        std::swap(__data, _Rhs.__data);
        return *this;
    }

    void reserve(size_type _Size)
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (_Size < size())
        {
            return;
        }
        pointer buf = _Alloc().allocate(_Size);
        for (iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i, ++count)
        {
            _Alloc().construct(&buf[count], *i);
        }
        std::swap(__data, buf);
        for (iterator i = &buf[0]; i != &buf[_Traits::length(buf)]; ++i)
        {
            _Alloc().destroy(i);
        }
        _Alloc().deallocate(buf, _Traits::length(buf));
    }

    operator const_pointer()
    {
        return __data;
    }

    operator pointer()
    {
        return __data;
    }

    template < typename _Traits1, typename _Alloc1 > friend std::basic_ostream<_Elem> &operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem> &_Stream, basic_string<_Elem, _Traits1, _Alloc1> &_Str)
    {
        return _Stream << _Str.c_str();
    }

    const_pointer data() const
    {
        return __data;
    }

    const_pointer c_str() const
    {
        return __data;
    }
private:
    pointer __data;
};

typedef basic_string<char> string;
typedef basic_string<wchar_t> wstring;
```

Of course, there is still a bit missing, but I'm sure you can implement that with a little online help.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of errors, not only with append

```
string(const char* s)
{
    _str = s;
}
```

The constructor is wrong, you should make a copy of `s` in order to free it later, this way:

```
~string()
{
    delete[] _str; // or free(_str) in case you use malloc/realloc, thanks Fred!
}
```

Private member variable:

```
private:
    const char* _str;
```

The internal string should not be const, you should be able to resize it later

```
const char operator[](int position)
{
    return _str[position];
}
```

You are missing a check: `length() > position`

```
void operator=(string s)
{
    _str = s.c_str();
}
```

You are not modifying `s`, it should be `const string& s`
You are also not copying `s.c_str()` which means that now `s` and `this` are sharing the same internal buffer

```
void append(string s) // s should be a const reference too
{
    size_t nlength = (length() + s.length());
    char* nstr = new char[nlength];
    for (int i = 0; i < length(); ++i)
    {
        nstr[i] = _str[i];
    }
    for (int i = length() + 1; i < nlength; ++i)
    {
        nstr[i] = s[(i - length() - 1)];
    }
    _str = const_cast<const char*>(nstr);
}
```

Should be easier to write in terms of `realloc`:

```
void append(string s)
{
    int start = length();
    _str = realloc(_str, length() + s.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        _str[start+i] = s[i];
    }
}
```

If you want to stick to `new` its OK, but you must free `_str` before assigning it to the new one.

The following operators should be const:

```
const char* c_str() const;
size_t length() const;
std::string str();
```

**Update:** Options for the constructor:

```
// option one (use delete[] to cleanup _str)
string(const char* s) {
    int n = strlen(s);
    _str = new char[n+1];
    memcpy(_str, s, n+1); // s is NULL terminated
}

// option two (use free() to cleanup _str)
string(const char* s) {
    int n = strlen(s);
    _str = (char*)malloc(n+1);
    memcpy(_str, s, n+1); // s is NULL terminated
}

// option 3: rely on append taking a char* argument
string(const char *s) : _str(NULL) {
    append(s, strlen(s));
}
..
void append(const string& s) {
    append(s.c_str(), s.length())
}
void append(const char *s, int len) {
  int start = _str ? length() : 0;
  _str = realloc(_str, start + len);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      _str[start+i] = s[i];
  }
}
```

**Update 2**: It will be better to use `size_t` or `unsigned int` instead of plain `int` because the size is always greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: Don't `free` something from `new` or `delete` something from `malloc`/`realloc`. Bad things could happen. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mixing-malloc-and-delete.html

Comment: @FredLarson so true :)

Comment: I said that because I'm very concerned about your recommendation of `realloc`, which would be bad when you hit that `delete []` in the destructor.

Comment: @FredLarson I know, I'm glad you mentioned it (you've got my upvote)

Comment: @ichramm - Thanks, how would I be able to make a copy of `s`?

Answer (score 1):

You have an off-by-one error in the second loop; the second string needs to be copied to `length()`, immediately after the end of the first:

```
for (int i = length(); i < nlength; ++i)
{
    nstr[i] = s[i - length()];
}
```

You'll also need to allocate one more byte to put a null terminator on the end.

Note that you don't need that scary-looking cast to add `const` to the pointer, since that's a perfectly safe thing to do. `const_cast` is only needed to *remove* qualifiers. You might also want to fix the memory leak and, for bonus points, cache the length so you don't have to read the entire string every time you want it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your most critical problem is in `char* nstr = new char[nlength];`.

You must change it to `char* nstr = new char[nlength+1];`.

Then, in function `append`, after the two `for` loops, set `nstr[nlength] = 0;`

Second, for better performance (as well as correct coding), you probably need to change `string s` to `const string& s` in the following functions:

```
void operator=(string s)
void append(string s)
void operator+=(string s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = length() + 1; i < nlength; ++i)
{
    nstr[i] = s[(i - length() - 1)];
}
```

You first copy chars up to length()-1 and then start back at length() + 1, so you skip a char and there could be anything in there after allocation(unless you do a memset beforehand).

Then you need to terminate your string with a null character(\0) so that the `std::string` that gets constructed on `str()` method return knows when to stop reading chars.